# When a room is selected how to make it no longer appear on the list?

Tags: filter, dropdown, google-app-maker

I use google appMaker for a short time.

I have a dropdown of several rooms and when a room is selected, I want it to no longer appear in this list.
Where do I need to set the code?

Thank you.

Comment: In Client script

Comment: I can not write the code that allows this

Comment: Please read stack overflow guidelines from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This is not the right place to ask someone for coding on your behalf.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using a calculated model containing the values used in the dropdown (by binding them as presented in the documentation), and as the user selects them, you can delete the selected from the datasource.